# Fastest/easiest way to copy paste between excel cell and browser text input box

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-chrome, browser, copy-paste

I'm working on a project where I need to copy cell content from excel over to a browser. Imagine this is a multi-monitor situation, and each row has necessary text input, corresponding to a link.

User would load the link, and need to input specific input in that row.

I'm curious if there are extensions, applications, or even faster excel methods to do this, vs. copy from excel, go to input in browser, paste.

Example, test@test.com is excel text, https://link1.com is link
User loads link, needs to copy/paste in test@test.com in an email box, move on to the next row with new input.

Any way to speed this up with other tools?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the fastest would be to write your HTML code directly instead of relying on the interface. I've used excel to help me write HTML code, but there could be other ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest way is to create a VBA macro that will open the browser, using the contents
of the active cell as URL.

This macro would do the job:

```
Sub OpenInBrowser()
    ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink Address:=ActiveCell.Text
End Sub
```

Some important points:

- The workbook file must be in format `.xlsm` rather than `.xlsx`
- The macro can be added to the banner menu as an icon, for ease of use.

For more information see the articles linked by the article
[VBA in Excel](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba.html).

Comment: Thanks.Any Idea how I could copy text in column b, when a hyperlink in column a is clicked? i.e. when cell A1 link clicked, copy value in B1, and so on?

Comment: You could use `Range("A1").Value` instead of `ActiveCell.Text`.